Не работает elementor при php-fpm+nginx 504 Gateway Time-out
Не работает elementor при php-fpm+nginx выдает 504 Gateway Time-out, либо вообще не загржается
в логах вот такая ошибка
recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 46.53.250.47, server: site.me, request: "GET /wp-admin/post.php?post=298621&action=elementor HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/site.me.sock:", host: "site.me", referrer: "https://.me/wp-admin/admin.php?page=vehica_panel_layouts_and_templates"
Конфиги

server {
    server_name site.me www.site.me  ;


    listen 000.00.00.00:443 ssl;
    

    ssl_certificate "/var/www/httpd-cert/site.me_2024-12-08-12-37_54.crt";
    ssl_certificate_key "/var/www/httpd-cert/site.me_2024-12-08-12-37_54.key";
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;


    http2 on;

    charset utf-8;

    set $root_path /var/www/site_usr/data/www/site.me;
    root $root_path;
    disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;

    location / {
        index index.php index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/site.me.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
     }



    location @fallback {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/site.me.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }

    include "/etc/nginx/fastpanel2-sites/site_usr/site.me.includes";
    include /etc/nginx/fastpanel2-includes/*.conf;


    error_log /var/www/site_usr/data/logs/site.me-frontend.error.log;
    access_log /var/www/site_usr/data/logs/site.me-frontend.access.log;
}


server {
    server_name site.me www.site.me  ;
    listen 000.00.00.00:80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

    error_log /var/www/site_usr/data/logs/site.me-frontend.error.log;
    access_log /var/www/site_usr/data/logs/site.me-frontend.access.log;
}

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 256
pm.min_spare_servers = 65
pm.max_spare_servers = 128
pm.max_requests = 6000
pm.process_idle_timeout = 60s
pm.status_path = /status


php_admin_value[date.timezone] = "Europe/Minsk"
php_admin_value[display_errors] = "off"
php_admin_value[log_errors] = "On"
php_admin_value[mail.add_x_header] = "On"
php_admin_value[max_execution_time] = "7200"
php_admin_value[max_file_uploads] = "10000"
php_admin_value[max_input_time] = "3600"
php_admin_value[max_input_vars] = "10000"
php_admin_value[memory_limit] = "1028M"
php_admin_value[opcache.blacklist_filename] = "/opt/opcache-blacklists/opcache-*.blacklist"
php_admin_value[opcache.max_accelerated_files] = "100000"
php_admin_value[output_buffering] = "4096"
php_admin_value[post_max_size] = "3000M"
php_admin_value[sendmail_path] = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f 'admin@site.me'"
php_admin_value[session.save_path] = "/var/www/site_usr/data/tmp"
php_admin_value[short_open_tag] = "On"
php_admin_value[upload_max_filesize] = "2000M"
php_admin_value[upload_tmp_dir] = "/var/www/site_usr/data/tmp"


catch_workers_output = no
access.format = "%{REMOTE_ADDR}e - [%t] \"%m %r%Q%q %{SERVER_PROTOCOL}e\" %s %{kilo}M \"%{HTTP_REFERER}e\" \"%{HTTP_USER_AGENT}e\""
access.log = /var/www/site_usr/data/logs/site.me-backend.access.log

